# Change,modify and repackage CXF-API source file

Tags: java, intellij-idea, cxf

I want to debug one of the class from  cxf-api-2.7.6 jar file ,downloaded the source file with the help of IntelliJ IDEA,but it does not contain POM file so what are  the exact steps to generate the jar file after making changes in the source file.

Any help or suggestion would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/creating-and-running-your-first-java-application.html#package

Comment: from command prompt use java -cvf some.jar *.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not modify a library and recompile it. It will be a pain to maintain. You will probably never be able to upgrade your library, and you might break some other behaviors.

If you just need to understand what is happening, you can use intellij debug tools as mentionned by Pim Hazebroek.

If you need to change the behavior of the library, you should :

- Check that you are not misusing the library (you could post your usecase on stackoverflow for advice)
- Check whether the latest version of cxf addresses your needs.
- Use a different library.
- Extend your current library (with inheritance for instance)

If however, you really need to modify cxf sources, you could clone https://github.com/apache/cxf, checkout the tag, modify the sources and rebuild.

Comment: I agree with you here completely,I just needed the code change just to put some log so that I can see what is really happening at production server, apart from this I don't have any intention to change the behavior of the library.

Comment: You could clone [https://github.com/apache/cxf], checkout the tag, modify the sources and rebuild.

Answer (score 2):

There is (usually) no need to modify the source and repackage it with the advanced breakpoints in IntelliJ.

Unless you want to drastically modify the behaviour of course... But for simple debugging tasks you can use the "evaluate and log" as demonstrated in String.toUpperCase here:[image]
It even provides code assistence.

Optionally you can uncheck the Suspend checkbox to remove the need to resume it when hit frequently.